# Customize FluentMigrator Postgres VersionInfo Schema

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent-migrator

I am trying to use FluentMigrator with PostgreSQL.

I have it running the migrations successfully, however the `VersionInfo` table is always in the `public` schema.  I read on the [FluentMigrator Wiki](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Create-custom-metadata-for-the-VersionInfo-table) that I could override the schema name, but it is not working.

Here is my class that I wrote to override the settings:

```
namespace YARA.Migrations
{
    using FluentMigrator.VersionTableInfo;

    [VersionTableMetaData]
    public class YaraVersionTable : DefaultVersionTableMetaData
    {
        public override string SchemaName
        {
            get { return "dbo"; }
        }

        public override string TableName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MigrationInfo";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the db after running the migrations; with neither the schema or changing the table name taking effect for the VersionInfo table.

Thoughts?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Luke It's been a really long time, I don't think I ever did; I'm not even sure where that tinkering project is anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create your class, in my case:

```
[VersionTableMetaData]
public class CustomMetadataTable : DefaultVersionTableMetaData
{
    public override string TableName => "__migrations_metadata";
}
```

Then add it to your services

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .UseStandardConfiguration()
            .AddFluentMigratorCore()
            .ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
                .AddPostgres92()
                .WithGlobalConnectionString(c => c.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("THECONNECTION_STRING"))
                .ScanIn(THEASSEMBLY).For.Migrations())
            .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddFluentMigratorConsole())
            .AddTransient<IVersionTableMetaData, CustomMetadataTable>()
            .BuildServiceProvider(false);
```

Just make sure is the last thing you register (just right above the last line)

Comment: Is there a reason why you register it as `Transient` instead of a `Singleton` or `Scoped` (as described in the documentation)? The object doesn't change, does it? https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/version-table-metadata.html

Comment: Good question. Can't remember. I'll get back on this later. Need to test the code